# Interpretation of absolute values

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

It is a simple regression, but I am wondering if I can interpret the absolute results or just say that they are different:

I am interested in finding out if the change of footprint is different in two periods (post-regulation). footprintDiffPrev describes the change in size to the previous model.

```
Call:
lm(formula = footprintDiffPrev ~ cafeClass + postRegulation + 
    fine + cafeClass * postRegulation + fine * postRegulation, 
    data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5925 -0.9159 -0.0385  0.8514  4.6075 

Coefficients:
                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                           1.51478    0.19510   7.764 1.78e-13 ***
cafeClasslarge                        0.67644    0.35937   1.882  0.06089 .  
cafeClassmidsize                     -0.08992    0.27157  -0.331  0.74081    
cafeClassminicompact                 -0.88978    0.69612  -1.278  0.20229    
cafeClasssmall suv                    2.04327    0.43099   4.741 3.47e-06 ***
cafeClassstandard suv                 0.34481    0.33202   1.039  0.29996    
cafeClasssubcompact                  -0.03460    0.43248  -0.080  0.93629    
cafeClasstwo seater                  -0.39512    0.46497  -0.850  0.39621    
postRegulation                       -0.26798    0.38928  -0.688  0.49181    
fine                                 -0.26555    0.24598  -1.080  0.28131    
cafeClasslarge:postRegulation        -0.96346    0.65446  -1.472  0.14216    
cafeClassmidsize:postRegulation       0.18847    0.51667   0.365  0.71557    
cafeClassminicompact:postRegulation   0.58298    0.97739   0.596  0.55137    
cafeClasssmall suv:postRegulation    -1.95160    0.60975  -3.201  0.00154 ** 
cafeClassstandard suv:postRegulation -0.88870    0.58385  -1.522  0.12916    
cafeClasssubcompact:postRegulation    1.10780    0.81101   1.366  0.17311    
cafeClasstwo seater:postRegulation    0.50646    0.79412   0.638  0.52418    
postRegulation:fine                   0.89110    0.42255   2.109  0.03589 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.336 on 266 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1461,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.09153 
F-statistic: 2.677 on 17 and 266 DF,  p-value: 0.0004524
```

(1) Is it possible to say that a small SUV is 2.04327 (pre-regulation) has a larger change than the base case. (2) A small SUV in the post-regulation period is 2.04327-1.95160 larger than the base case which is a non-small SUV in the pre-regulation.
(3) (and most important) the difference between a small SUV in pre- and post regulation period is that a small SUV in post-regulation is 1.95160 smaller than a SUV in pre-regulation period.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a first step it would be best to see whether you actually need all the interactions in your model (with `drop1`.

I think you are working along the right lines but I think you have left out some of the main effects. So to get the predicted mean for postreg suv you need not just the main effect for suv but also for postreg (which I do not think you have taken into account) and then also the interaction effect. Note that you are holding fine constant which is probably what you intend but I point out for completeness.